# How to remove 0 after the fraction point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following variable:

```
var result = 30.03692740;
```

I want to remove `0` after `.` , So that the final result would be:

> 30.3692740

How to do that?

I tried:

```
result = result.replace('.0' , '.');
```

But it's not working.

Comment: `(result.toString())`

Comment: A number is not a string, I hope you are aware.

Comment: note: your end result can only be `30.3692740` if your initial assignment and end result is a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) works with strings. You need to convert the number to string to perform this operation:

```js
var result = 30.03692740;
result = result.toString();
result = result.replace('.0', '.');
result = parseFloat(result);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I wouldn't parseFloat ... OP wants the trailing `0`

Comment: @JaromandaX -- haha. The trailing 0 wasn't still with the original assignment `result = 30.03692740`.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive my curiosity but why'd you wanna do that ?

Answer is:

```
var result = 30.03692740; 
result = result.toString().replace('.0' , '.');
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, `replace()` works with strings, so you need to first convert the number to string. Using `.toString()` to do the conversion is the clearest way, but if performance is critical, then this is faster:

```
result = (result + "").replace('.0' , '.');
```

Alternatively, you can use math instead of converting to string. First separate the integral and decimal parts, multiply the decimal part by 10 to remove the first zero, and then add the two parts again together. The only issue with this approach is that you run into floating number precision. Usually this is fine and can be ignored, but if it is an issue, it can be fixed with `.toFixed()`:

```js
var result = 30.03692740;
result = parseInt(result) + (result % 1 * 10);
console.log(result);
console.log(result.toFixed(6));
```